Issue with FME WMS basemap not inputting
very new to FME, I'm having an issue where I can't inseret the basemaps, in QGIS all that is needed is the URL, I don't know why in the constraints tab the layer is required? What do I need to put into the layer tab for this to work?


WMS do not have x,y,z parameters; or in other words your service is not a WMS

Google Maps uses (vt) [Vector Tiles]
Note: Using FME 2024 (Form) hence looks different.
For WMS in FME (background maps)
use WMS
like
https://www.geoportal.hessen.de/mapbender/php/wms.php?inspire=1&layer_id=59841&request=GetCapabilities&service=WMS&version=1.3.0&INSPIRE=1

Load 
Loads the maps when set.


Great thank you, geoportal website is a big help.
